# Social implication of lion-people living with normal humans and how to make them into free folk and not slaves while maintaing their role as defenders

Tags: creature-design, society, alternate-worlds, alternate-reality, alternate-earth

[image]

Lion-people are kidnapped at birth from humans. Why?

- Because Lion-folk prey on humans as a form of sport and entertainment
- Kidnapped cubs of lion-folk are groomed in ''loving'' families in order  to grow as defenders of society
- The heightened senses of kidnapped lion folk are vital to traking predators and spotting ambushers
- Kidnapped cubs are often used to escort merchants, farmers and children
- Kidnapped lion-folk are the equivalent of real world wolves raised as dogs to protect the sheep herd from wolves
- Just like herding dogs, Kidnapped lion-folk are taller, heavier, smarter and stronger than their wild counter part
- Wild lion-folk live in societies of various types but the most common ones are fishing tribes or  raider tribes riding horses like the mongols which terrorized early europe.
- Lion-folk in general can speak, although kidnapped ones have the ability to pronounce sounds that the wild counter part can't
- Wild Lion-folk are on average 170 centimetres tall (5'6 feet) by 75kg (165lbs) but domesticated lion-folk rarely get below 190 (6'2 feet) centimetres by 100kg (225lbs) also the domesticated version has slightly more loose skin but not in the same way of obese people that lost weight but the kind of loose skin that bears or tigers have, the type of loose skin that reduces the chance of being perforated by piercing or cutting blows, kind of the same reason herding dogs have so much loose skin but domesticated lion folk aren't this extreme and their loose skin is covered in foor and goes unnoticed (just an excuses because I can't bother to model and animate loose skin)
- Both versions of the species are omnivorous in nature but the ''domesticated'' type has longer intestines and can tollerate a 90% vegetarian diet

The step of a lion-folk is so soft, their movments are so silent that even a trained soldier could realize way too late of the dangerous arrow that's now perforating the back of their skull, many animals were attempted to be used as living ''alarms'' like small birds or cats for example, but only domesticated lion-folk are able to not only speak and tell you where the enemy is exactly but can also defend you from them.

Just like most people aren't gonna hate domesticated dogs because wolves used to eat people, at most they are gonna hate them because they pee everywhere and bark at night, most humans do not hate domesticated lion-folk and they themselves, just like dogs do not identify as being part of the wolves anymore.

**Question**

How would one organize a society where lion-folk started a stock brainwashed slaves for protection  but evolved to be part of normal people while still maintaining them as valuable defenses of the people without enslaving them once the ''brainwashing'' doesn't work anymore since now all domesticated lion folk know the truth of they came to be and that some of them might have different ideals and want to get different jobs ?

Comment: What makes you think that there's a singular answer to this question. We're not a brainstorming site. You can choose to organize your society however your want. Asking us to build your world for you isn't an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: Why do you need them to be brainwashed? There are many reasons why they might choose to be defenders. If your lionfolk are intelligent, then they must have culture. If they have culture, they will have different cultures. Maybe some lionfolk simply choose to live among humans and find the idea of hunting intelligent species anathema.

Comment: @sphennings what makes you think this websites is about giving singular answers?  There's literal thousands of questions about organizing societies in this websites, each one with more than 1 answer, and there are more than 1 tags dedicated to it. What's the point of this website existing if the answers are ''it's your world do what you want?'' At this point the only reason this website exists is because the science stacks are dead, the biology stacks too, economy stacks too... this is not worldbuilding.stack but just ''meh the only thing availble.stackexchange''

Comment: @sphennings I mean, the Moderators literally advise everyone to not accept answers too soon to allow the interest for the question to grow so that it gets MORE THAN ONE ANSWER  since more answers  = more people can be helped. This is not stackoverflow where you get 1 answer per question then the question is lost in time for 10 years

Comment: This is too broad. A question that takes a paragraph to ask needs more focus by definition. Asking us to write a significant portion of your civilization's history violates the we do worldbuilding, not storybuilding rule. You've not explained anything about how you'll judge a best answer, which makes all answers of equal value (prohibited). How do you judge the difference between "You pay them to join the military" and "you create a complicated social structure based on honor and duty to favor the psycholoical nature of lion-people and encourage their particpation without slavery"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lion folk / human crossbreeds.**

As time goes by most people will have some lion folk blood.  Those with more of the relevant abilities will be defenders and soft steppers.  Others will be tax doers or turf farmers.  When a child is born who really looks like a wild lion folk it will cause comment and complement.  Also true for a child born with a flat face, like the pictures of the human ancients.